# Pressing enter in auto suggest box is submitting main form

Tags: php, autocomplete

I've used autoSuggest in PHP now pressing enter in auto suggest box is submitting main form. How do i disable form submission while I use auto suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for, but you might consider using jQuery and preventDefault(). Check it out: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

im guessing you want something like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#changeSite").keypress(function (event){ return event.keyCode == 13 ? false : true; });
});
```

change #changeSite to match your form

Answer (score 0):

When you call your keypress function and bind it to an event, make sure the event doesn't call the form using `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$("#input_id").keypress(function (event){ 
   event.preventDefault();
   if(event.keyCode==13){
     // call auto complete function
   } else {
     return false;
   }
});
```